# Ошибка при вызове обученной модели keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, model

Пытаюсь вызвать обученную модель Keras:

```
import keras

new_model = keras.models.load_model("/Users/alex/Desktop/model.h5")
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-7f061beafbf6> in <module>()
      1 import keras
      2 
----> 3 new_model = keras.models.load_model("/Users/alex/Desktop/model.h5")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py in parse_saved_model(export_dir)
    111                   (export_dir,
    112                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PBTXT,
--> 113                    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
    114 
    115 

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /Users/alex/Desktop/model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать `.h5`. Покажите, как сохраняли модель, если это делали Вы.

Comment: Также попробуйте начать путь с `./`, а не со `/`. Этот вариант более предпочтителен, чем предыдущий, начните с него.

Comment: MODEL_FILE = "model.h5"
model.save_weights(MODEL_FILE)

Comment: вызываю модель на mac os. поэтому такой путь

Comment: Насколько я помню, чтобы использовать `load()`, нужно сохранять с помощью `save()`, а не `save_weights()`

Comment: модель обучил и сохранил: model.save_weights(model_file)

Comment: Вы уверены, что данный файл существует по этому пути?

Comment: попробую сейчас

Comment: конечно существует. я его нахожу, правой кнопкой копировать путь и вставляю в код путь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117113/discussion-between-v-mor-and-albra).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь:

Comment: Вот этот Ваш совет сработал:и ещё в функции save используйте доп параметр save_format='h5'. То есть model.save('Ваш путь', save_format='h5')
  
Вот так в общем: model.save_weights(model_file, save_format='h5')

Comment: Сейчас вынесу в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы использовать `model.load()`, которая загружает всю модель целиком, а не только веса, сохранять нужно тоже ВСЮ модель. А делается это с помощью `model.save()`.

Сохраняйте так:

```python
model.save(model_file, save_format='h5')
```

как гласит [документация](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/), по умолчанию модели сохраняются не в формате h5, а в формате tf. Следовательно, необходимо явно указать формат сохранения.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо V-Mor за помощь. Заработало по его совету:

в функции save используйте доп параметр save_format='h5'. То есть model.save('Ваш путь', save_format='h5') Вот так в общем: model.save_weights(model_file, save_format='h5')

Comment: Вы по итогу `save` или `save_weights` использвоали? А то я напутал немного

Comment: использовал save

Comment: Спасибо V-Mor за своевременный совет. Благодаря ему все успел и занял 2-е место в хакатоне Сбербанка. Спасибо.

Comment: Раньше до использования обученной модели не доходило никогда, останавливался всегда на этапе повышения точности обучения, а здесь нужно было создать в итоге web-сервис на Django с искусственным интеллектом